# How to specify which rows/tables HTML should export?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, export

Hi I want to download a HTMl table to my pc
I manage to do it using sample code found on the net
This however download all the tables displayed
How do I specify which table i want to download

```
function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
var csv = [];
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
        row.push(cols[j].innerText);

    csv.push(row.join(","));        
}

// Download CSV file
downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
```

}

Comment: Are you asking how to download specific table or row? Based on your code, you're trying to download some rows.

Comment: `var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table:nth-of-type(X) tr");` `X={number position of table}` this may work in a typical layout hard to say without HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function exportTableToCSV(tableNumber, filename) {
  var csv = [];
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table");

  var rows = tables[tableNumber].querySelectorAll("tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
      row.push(cols[j].innerText);

      csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }

    // Download CSV file
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
  }
}
```

Now you can input the table number that you want to download

Comment: HI Tx but this still download all tables on the page. Ive replaced tables[tableNumber] with tables[1] for there is 2 tables on the page and I only want to download table 2

Comment: @TheWizard Sorry just saw you comments now